# Making a range verb in J

Tags: j

J is a fantastic programming language that I have decided to learn. As a simple exercise, I decided to emulate a range. There is a builtin function `i.` that creates a range `0..i-1`. Using some math, I have that this is the range between `a` and `b`:

```
 a + i. (b - a - 1)
```

*Success!* I thought. Now, the "simple" task of converting to a verb is set before me. This is my problem now. I have `a` (the left argument) being called on both sides of the verb `+`. I thought of using evoke, but I am not sure as how to make it work.

So my question stands: How do I convert an expression of the form `a f (a g b)` or, more specifically, `a f (a g b h c)` (and similar forms) to a pure verb? I don't want to use explicit arguments, for what's the fun in that? ;)

**EDIT** My solution is as thus:

```
range =: [(+i.)>:@-~
```

Comment: Nice work with that solution, although you don't actually need the ~ with + because + is reflexive. range =: [(+i.)>:@-~ should work just as well.

Comment: @bob so it is! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert an expression of the form `x f (x g y)` to a form of `x h y` you can use a dyadic fork:

```
x (F G H) y = (x F y) G (x H y)
```

and the identity verb: `x [ y = x`, making:

```
x ([ f g) y  = (x [ y) f (x g y) = x f (x g y)
```

So the verb you are looking for is `h =: [ f g`

Comment: Verbs in J have right and (optionally) left arguments; you can't have a general form for a verb needing `a`, `b`, **and** `c`. Usually some of them would be boxed and passed as one argument.

Comment: Thank you for you invaluable help!

Comment: I know nothing about J, but those unclosed square brackets make me feel uncomfortable.

Comment: @flawr you feel my pain :P

Comment: The [ returns the left of two arguments and the ] returns the right of two arguments. So  a [ b returns a and a] b returns b. They aren't used as a square bracket pair in J but as right and left operators. It does take a little getting used to, but isn't really conceptually difficult.